# R Shiny: setExtremes in Highcharts (rCharts) on page load

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I have a shiny app that users the rCharts library to create a Highcharts chart.  When the app first starts, I'd like the app to be zoomed in to a particular region.

The Highcharts method is setExtremes() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

The following is a minimal example that can be run in interactive R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("title"),
    sidebarPanel('sidebar'),
    mainPanel(showOutput("testPlot", "Highcharts"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$testPlot <- renderChart2({
      hc <- Highcharts$new()
      hc$xAxis(categories=c('Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su',
                            'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'))
      hc$series(data=c(7, 1, 4, 2.5, 3.25, 2.875, 3.0625, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3))
      setX <- "#! function() {
                 var cht = this;
                 var chtXAxis = this.xAxis[0];
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   console.log(chtXAxis.getExtremes().max); // correctly shows 13 in the console
                   chtXAxis.setExtremes(2, 10);
                   console.log(chtXAxis.getExtremes().max); // nothing in the console
                   cht.showResetZoom();
                 }, 2000)
               } !#"
      hc$chart(type="spline", zoomType='xy', events=list(load=setX))

      hc$set(domID="testPlot")
      return(hc)
    })
  }
))
```

You can see in the console that the getExtremes() method is successful, but the setExtremes() method doesn't work.  I have no idea why.

Can anyone help fix this, or give a recommendation on how better to set the extremes upon loading?

Comment: It worked for me, with Chrome and Firefox, I see 13 and 10 in the console. Maybe update rCharts.

Comment: Ooof, good thinking.  It works for me now too.  Update the package.  That's the lesson.  Thank you so much for trying it out and answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victorp's reply showed that there was nothing fundamentally wrong with my code, but rCharts was, indeed, old.  The above code should work if your version of rCharts is newer than today's date, perhaps with some older versions too.  I don't know which release I was working on, but it would have been some months old.

Thanks to Victorp.